# Algorithm to get next weekday based on today

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose today is Thursday. I have 1 flag for both Wednesday and Friday.

If I create a temporary table then it will look like

```
ID  WeekDay     XFlag
==================================
1   Mon         0    
2   Tue         0    
3   Wed         1    
4   Thu         0    
5   Fri         1    
6   Sat         0    
7   Sun         0
```

Now, as we assumed today is *Thursday*, the next day when `XFlag` value 1 is Friday.

Any or all weekdays can be marked/flagged 1. But, I ultimately want to get the next weekday based on today. So, my result will be `Fri` for this in a varchar variable in a stored procedure.
Here, if today is wed then also result will be "Fri". But if today is "Fri" result will be "Wed". So, please care for such cases also. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the next day but the challenge is that the week days form a cycle.  You can handle this using `order by` and some cleverness:

```
select top 1 tt.*
from TemporaryTable tt
where flag = 1
order by (7 + tt.id - datepart(dw, getdate())) % 7
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14549) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

If datefirst might be set differently, you can do the join on the date name.  Just a bit more complicated with the `order by` condition:

```
select top 1 tt.*
from TemporaryTable tt cross join
     (select id from TemporaryTable tt where Weekday = left(datepart(dw, getdate()), 3)
     ) as startid
where flag = 1
order by (tt.id - startid.id + 7) % 7;
```

This assumes, of course, that the language being returned is English.

Comment: `mod()` doesn't exist in SQL Server, and I think that this answer may also depend on what `DATEFIRST` settings are in effect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . It is documented as being in 2012 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767(v=sql.110).aspx), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: He tagged 2008... tt.id - (datepart(dw, getdate()) % 7) should work

Comment: That's in the PowerPivot reference, not T-SQL. Also, if `DATEFIRST` is set to e.g. 4, this returns Wednesday when `getdate()` is returning e.g. 20140206, when it should return Friday.

Comment: damien makes a good point about DATEFIRST.  I think you can get around it, though, with something like this (untested):  ORDER BY (tt.id + @@DATEFIRST % 7) - (datepart(dw, getdate()) % 7)

Comment: @dazedandconfused . . . I edited the answer to use day-of-week name instead.

Comment: it is possible to avoid datefirst without making it complicated

Answer (score 1):

I've gone quite procedural here, but the parts can be incorporated into a larger query, rather than using local variables, if required:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,Weekday char(3) not null,XFlag bit not null)
insert into @t(ID,WeekDay,XFlag) values
(1,'Mon',0),(2,'Tue',0),(3,'Wed',1),
(4,'Thu',0),(5,'Fri',1),(6,'Sat',0), 
(7,'Sun',0)

declare @Today int
declare @NextDay int

--Set today, in a DATEFIRST safe manner
set @Today = ((DATEPART(weekday,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 7) --Today
       - DATEPART(weekday,'20140106') --Known Monday
       ) % 7 + 1

set @NextDay = COALESCE((select MIN(ID) from @t where XFlag = 1 and ID > @Today),
                        (select MIN(ID) from @t where XFlag = 1))

select Weekday from @t where ID = @NextDay
```

Hopefully it's (relatively) easy to see how I'm thinking.

Setting `@Today` is probably the most complex part, and that only because I'm trying to write code that can be run by anyone, anywhere, without having to adjust either it or their `DATEFIRST` setting. We subtract the results of two calls to `DATEPART(weekday,...` where we know that one of them is definitely a Monday, and we've also set it up so that we always produce a positive result. We then use `% 7` to ensure that it's in the range 0-6, corresponding to Monday-Sunday, and then add 1 so that the values produced by this expression match the `ID`s in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version of @GordonLinoff's answer that doesn't rely on local datefirst settings

```
select top 1 *
from <table>
where Xflag = 1
order by datediff(d, id-1, current_timestamp) % 7 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Here WorkingDay is TableName

```
Select *,
    CASE 
         WHEN
        (Select top 1 WeekDay From WorkingDay WHERE ID > W.ID AND XFLAG=1 ORDER BY ID) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN (Select top 1 WeekDay From WorkingDay WHERE ID > W.ID AND XFLAG=1 ORDER BY ID)
        ELSE
        (Select top 1 WeekDay From WorkingDay WHERE ID < W.ID AND XFLAG=1 ORDER BY ID)
        END AS NextWorkingDay       
    From  WorkingDay   W
    Order By ID
```